# Display first 3 characters using gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have a column with codes of 4 characters and I would like to make a second column which only gives the first 3 characters of the first columns.

So if the first code is 1234 I would like to have 123 in the second column.

I am currently looking into gsub and with the following code I can display the first character.

```
code<-1234 
gsub("(?<!^)(..)", "", code, perl=TRUE)
```

Does anyone know how I could extract the first three characters?

Comment: `substr(code, 1, 3)` or `sub("^(.{3}).*", "\\1", code)`

Comment: Much simpler than the gsub method, thanks Akrun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can either use `substr`

```
substr(code, 1, 3)
```

or with `sub` to capture the three characters (`(.{3})`) from the start (`^`) of the string as a group followed by other character and replace with the backreference (`\\1`) of the capture group

```
sub("^(.{3}).*", "\\1", code)
```